# angular-http-auth with $http transformResponse

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-http-auth

I'm using [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) to show a login dialog whenever a 401 "unauthorized" response is returned from the server.

Since I'm cool, I also try to deserialize response objects in my services. For example, if a service requests a `car` and the response is `{make: Honda, model: Civic}`, I try to deserialize that into a `Car` object using `transformResponse`.

For example:

```
getCar: function() {
    return $http.get('/api/car', {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
            var c = angular.fromJson(data);
            return new Car(c);
        }
    });
}
```

This doesn't work with [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth). If the response was a 401 Unauthorized, you'll get a javascript error. It's because angular will try to run that `transformResponse` code even if the response was a 401.

It turns out that `$http` interceptors (which is what [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) uses) are run AFTER the `transformResponse` code.  That's a huge problem, because none of that code in `transformResponse` will work if the server response was a 401 (there wouldn't be any `data`)

Is this a problem for anyone else?  How did you get around it?  Am I not to use `transformResponse` if I use `$http` interceptors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late to the party, I know, but to anyone coming here from Google like I did (I also posted this as a comment on a [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7594) filed with the Angular repo):

I also found it to be confusing that response interceptors run *after* the `transformResponse` method. I added a method to `$http.defaults.transformResponse`. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request) is an example from the documentation on how to do that.

So, if you need to basically have a response interceptor that runs *before* the `transformResponse` method, this should do it:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .run(function ($http) {
    $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (data, headers) {
      // do stuff here before the response transformation

      // Be sure to return `data` so that the next function in the queue can use it.
      // Your services won't load otherwise!
      return data;
    });
  });
```

If your services or http calls don't have their own response transformer, you're good now.

If your services do have their own `transformResponse` method, they will actually override all default transformers (I found this out after a long read of the documentation), and the above code will not run.

To circumvent this, you can follow [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem I don't use `transformResponse` anymore. I just can't see the point of `transformResponse` if it runs before $http interceptors.

In order to use [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) and also deserialize responses in your services, you can write your services so that they execute the HTTP request first and then deserialize the response in a callback function.

As an example, here is how I would have restructured the example in the OP:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vloMQv?p=info)

```
services.factory('HttpCarService', function($resource, $q) {
  var resource = $resource('/api/car');

  return {

    getCar: function() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var car = null;

      var successCallback = function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var c = angular.fromJson(data);
        car = new Car(c);
        deferred.resolve(car);
      };

      var errorCallback = function(data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject("something wrong");
      };

      var result = resource.get(successCallback, errorCallback);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };

});
```

This pattern will also work if `data` is an array.

`$http` interceptors will run before either of the callback methods are executed. If your $resource needs url params, you can make the getCar() function accept a config object as a parameter, and pass the necessary information on when you make the $resource.get() call.